# Adding event listeners in d3.js

Tags: events, d3.js, append, listener, addition

I have a simple question but unfortunately I think I am doing something wrong.

I have a page which generates multiple independent charts. I would like to add an event listener for each of this charts which depends on a radio button set. For example let's say there are 3 options in the radio buttons [A,B,C] and depending on which button is selected, the charts should visualize a different variable. Each chart is generated asynchronously using AJAX calls, and is structured as a reusable chart (as described here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)

What I have done at the moment is that these charts create their own event listener as here:

```
d3.selectAll(".global-control").on("change.pie", readjustPie);
```

and

```
d3.selectAll(".global-control").on("change.scatter", readjustScatter);
```

Both readjustPie and readjustScatter are functions in different 'reusable charts' (eg pieChart() and ScatterChart())

Obviously one listener is overwritten when the newest code is executed (charts are generated asynchronously). What I would like to do is something like instead of adding the event listener in each function, to be able to append a listener. I have tried the option of

```
d3.selectAll(".global-control")
.on("change.pie", readjustPie)
.on("change.scatter", readjustScatter);
```

but it doesn't work as the functions (readjust*) cannot be found (obviously, they are not global functions).

Is such an event-appending possible?

Sorry if the question is stupid, but I would appreciate any help.

Best,
Nikos

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the reusable charts should not know about the form controls if you want to keep your code modular and testable. I would expose the "readjustPie" on the charts API and call it from the global-control event, something like:

```
d3.selectAll(".global-control")
  .on("change.pie", changePieValue)

function changePieValue(_ctrl){
  var ctrlValue = _ctrl.grabYourValueHere;
  pieChart.readjustPie(_ctrlValue);
  d3.select('#pie-chart-container1')
    .call(pieChart)
}
```

Here is an example: http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/4213367